# Teamcity nuget server settings

Tags: .net, nuget, teamcity, nuget-server, teamcity-9.0

I have TeamCity 9 with enabled nuget server. I configured creating nuget packages after build. I made all steps in this guide https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/12/setting-up-teamcity-as-a-native-nuget-server/

Is there a way to set nguet server settings?

Comment: What type of setting would you like to set? As far as I know currently it's not possible to configure TeamCity NuGet feed.

Comment: Share a snapshot of your current build settings